# Pandas - Merging a grouped column to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

One of my dataframes contains columns

```
WR          K ID
SP-RS-001   K001
SP-RS-001   K002
SP-RS-001   K006
SP-RS-002   K002
SP-RS-002   K007
SP-RS-002   K008
```

and the other has [EDIT]

```
U Code     CO Code    K ID
C001       C001.01    K001
C001       C001.02    K002
C001       C001.03    K006
C002       C002.01    K001
C002       C002.02    K006
```

I need another column in this dataframe which gives

```
U Code     K ID               WR
C001       K001, K002, K006   SP-RS-001, SP-RS-002
C002       K001, K006         SP-RS-001
C003       K002, K007         SP-RS-001, SP-RS-002
```

How can I do that? Thanks! :)

Comment: `K001, K002, K006` is this one string or a list of strings?

Comment: @suicidalteddy It's a concatenated string based on grouping of a column. I used `.groupby('col_name').agg({'K ID' : ', '.join})`

Comment: @harry04 can you provide the DataFrame that came from? It would be easier to do a merge and groupby in a single step

Comment: @user3483203 made an edit to the above table. That's what it initially looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm assuming **C003** entry was a mistake (in your original question), I believe the following will work for you. It wasn't apparent which type of *merge* you wanted, so I assumed an **inner merge**.

Load Dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'WR': ['SP-RS-001', 'SP-RS-001', 'SP-RS-001', 'SP-RS-002', 'SP-RS-002', 'SP-RS-002'],
                'K_ID': ['K001', 'K002', 'K006', 'K002', 'K007', 'K008']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'U_Code': ['C001', 'C001', 'C001', 'C002', 'C002'],
                    'C0_Code': ['C001.01', 'C001.02', 'C001.03', 'C002.01', 'C002.02'],
                    'K_ID': ['K001', 'K002', 'K006', 'K001', 'K006']})
```

Merge on **K_ID**:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on='K_ID', how='inner')[['U_Code', 'K_ID', 'WR']]
```

This gives us:

[image]

and finally, a groupby on **U_CODE** with the following aggregating function:

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series(dict(K_ID = ', '.join(x['K_ID'].unique()), 
                    WR = ', '.join(x['WR'].unique())))

df = df.groupby(['U_Code']).apply(f)
```

Which gives us:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: With some changes to the dictionary in the `f(x)`, it worked for me! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'K ID')

df4 =df3.groupby('U Code')['K ID','WR'].agg({'K ID': lambda x: ','.join(x), 'WR': lambda x: ','.join(x)})
```